# I'm stuck with twitter oauth api

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to get the home feed on twitter with twitter oauth api. I tried with this code and first it worked. But now it just gives me a blank page. But my big question is how I can get the text and date and everything important. This is my code:

EDIT: I got the code working, but I still wonder how I can get the text from each post the array.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('twitter/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('twitter/config.php');


/* If access tokens are not available redirect to connect page. */
if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
    header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}
/* Get user access tokens out of the session. */
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];

/* Create a TwitterOauth object with consumer/user tokens. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

/* If method is set change API call made. Test is called by default. */
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

/* Some example calls */
//$connection->get('users/show', array('screen_name' => 'alexastely'));

$feed = $connection->get('statuses/home_timeline');
//echo $feed;
print_r($feed);

//$connection->post('statuses/destroy', array('id' => 5437877770));
//$connection->post('friendships/create', array('id' => 9436992));
//$connection->post('friendships/destroy', array('id' => 9436992));

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you mean?

```
$feed = $connection->get('statuses/home_timeline');

foreach($feed as $post) {
    echo $post['text'];
    echo $post['created_at'];
}
```

You can read more about tweet object here - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets

Edit:

```
$feed = $connection->get('statuses/home_timeline');

foreach($feed as $post) {
    echo $post->text;
    echo $post->created_at;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this  is whati mean, but its not working. When I write:

$feed = $connection->get('statuses/home_timeline');
foreach($feed as $post) {
    print_r($post);
}

, everything works and it prints out an array. But when I write this:

$feed = $connection->get('statuses/home_timeline');

foreach($feed as $post) {
    echo $post['text'];
    echo $post['created_at']
}

,it just gives me a blank page! I have no idea why it is so... Please help me!

Comment: When you print_r your feed what you see? Are you sure you get any results?

Comment: This works:
 foreach($feed as $post) {
    print_r($post);
 echo "<hr />";
}
, and it prints out something like this for each post:
stdClass Object ( [created_at] => Mon Nov 18 15:30:01 +0000 2013 [id] => 402458681712726016 [id_str] => 402458681712726016 [text] => New gallery of #Gandalf images from #TheHobbit The Desolation of Smaug. http://t.co/YzeoVXS9yc [source] => web [truncated] => [in_reply_to_status_id] => [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => [in_reply_to_user_id] => [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => [in_reply_to_screen_name] => [user] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 104969057 [id_str]...(more)

Comment: I edited my answers, it's object not array. You should also should turn display_erros, then you wont get only blank page.